# How to apply 1 adjustment curve to to every layer before exporting layers(render as video)?

Tags: video, photoshop, photoshop-cs4

Hi
Bit of a tricky question as I'm using Photoshop to color correct a video file. First importing frames as layers. The I simply export 'render video'. Easy enough. But I want to apply just 1 adjustment curve to each and every layer BEFORE I export-render. Because I might have several hundred layers, not practical to do manually.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to this in Photoshop?

Anyway, Do not do it with lots of layers, a 'better' way will be to run an action for each frame as a separate file and color correct it.

IMHO you may consider using video editing software.  Avisynth is free and you can use [`Levels()`](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/Levels) and [`RGBAdjust()`](http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/RGBAdjust) to color correct it.

Answer (score -2):

Apply adjustment curve to current layer.At that time, adjustment curve is applied to all layers.
And then merge the adjustment curve layer to current layer(use short key : Ctrl+E).
So adjustment curve should apply to only current layer